# Why would you Truncate immediately before Dropping a temp table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, temp-tables

I see some code where the author has truncated a temp table immediately before dropping the temp table. Is there a reason for doing this?

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #Temp
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4163 has some excellent analysis. TL;DR: DROP without TRUNCATE is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the author was under the impression that DROP TABLE would be quicker if the table was already empty and knew that TRUNCATE would be quicker than DELETE.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason is that a `DROP TABLE` is a fully logged operation, so by truncating first (which is never logged) you lower transactional logging overhead.

Comment: I've learned recently that a truncate is logged (but not like a delete is) but I understand your point

Comment: Joe you got it reversed.  Delete is logged truncate is not.   +1 Alex as I did not know drop was logged (and to me it does not make sense).

Answer (score 1):

Could possibly be a knucklehead. (not that I'm perfect).

Answer (score 1):

On very large temp tables, it's sometimes faster to truncate first then drop because truncate simply moves a pointer.  It's normally not needed since temp tables drop on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that the coder is trying to avoid a delayed drop that will occur when temp table is larger than 8MB. I.e. truncate it then drop it. I'm not sure if the SQL engine will be fooled by this but it might force synchronous clean up. I can't see why you'd want to do this, maybe to avoid some problem with accumulating delayed drops (Temp tables for destruction)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly to see if the `TRUNCATE` command throws an exception due to existing foreign keys?

Comment: I suppose that isn't out of the realm of possibilities but this particular code is not in any sort of error handling block

Comment: I can't think of any other reason then, other than a wrong assumption (as mentioned in the answer from CodeByMoonlight)